# Shuffle and spread uniformly one kind of row in a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dataset, shuffle

I have a dataset csv file with features and predictions looking like that:

```
Feature1    Feature2    Prediction
214         ast         0
222         bbr         0
845         iop         0
110         frn         1
...
```

I am trying to shuffle the csv file this way:

```
import csv
import random

with open("dataset.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    header, l = next(r), list(r)

random.shuffle(l)

with open("dataset_shuffled.csv", "wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows([header] + l)
```

However the lines with a 1 prediction are only 1% of the full dataset.
As I want to separate this dataset into train/test sets, I would like to spread equally/uniformly the 1 predictions in the dataset.

How can I do that during the shuffling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *reinventing the wheel* maybe you can use a combination of [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org). In particular you can read a csv in a Pandas Dataframe like:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('your_csv.csv')
```

at this point you may want to create `x` (feature set) and `y` (target):

```
x = df[['Feature1', 'Feature2']]
y = df[['Prediction']]
```

and use Scikit-Learn to create training and test sets:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

check [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for further details about `train_test_split`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Train_test_split function will automatically spread the positive examples proportionally between both sets? It is not very clear to me from the documentation.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier `train_test_split` will split the data randomly in train and test; what you should correctly expect is that: **the proportion of positive and negative examples is the same in training and test set**. So, if you have 10000 examples and 100 are positive you should expect ~70 positive in training and ~30 positive in test (assuming `test_size=0.33`).

Comment: ok but if the split is random and my 100 positive examples are grouped in the begining of my dataset, will it break this?

Comment: @VincentTeyssier read the documentation for the keyword: `shuffle`.

Comment: yes, that's what is unclear to me: "Shuffle arrays or sparse matrices in a consistent way" what is the definition of a "consistent way" :)

Comment: [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html): **shuffle**: `boolean, optional (default=True)` *Whether or not to shuffle the data before splitting. If shuffle=False then stratify must be None*. By default it shuffles the data.

Comment: Yes it shuffles. But in my view shuffle is a random process, the question here is to spread equally/uniformly the positive examples. For ex 100 / 10000 pos in the dataset, 70/7000 train 30/3000 test... is that what they call "consistent way" `?